# change <div> location with just .css edit

Tags: html, css

Having 4 `<div class="myField">` each one below the other  -

**http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/6Mdmd/**

I want to change its view to be two couple of face each other - like the result in -

**http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/q8EK5/**

**but with the requirement** that it would be with just edit the `.css` - mean keep on same `<body>` .

How could I get that ?

Comment: Is this what you mean? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Mdmd/1/)

Comment: See my approach: (http://jsfiddle.net/Trimax/q8EK5/1/)

Comment: @Trimax The user is trying to achieve this effect purely using CSS and not modifying the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following CSS:

```
.myField {
    float: left;
}

.myField:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

The first rule will float the elements. The second rule says that the element after every 2 elements will clear the float meaning it will fall to the next line.

If you then decided you wanted 3 per row you could easily modify this to accommodate:

```
.myField:nth-child(3n+1) {
```

Please be aware this uses CSS3 selectors therefore won't work in IE8 or below without using something like selectivizr: http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: does the answer of @Alex uses CSS3 too ?

Comment: Yes. nth-child is a CSS3 selector.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**css**

```
.myField:nth-child(1){
    float:left;
}

.myField:nth-child(3){
    float:left;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y64Kw/)

Comment: This works but will only apply if there's 4 elements. If the user adds more he'll need to add more styling. You'd probably be better using `.myField:nth-child(odd) { float: left; }` if you were doing it this way.

Comment: True, but i create it just for this example. :)